# Number of rows and cols in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I want to know the number of rows and columns in a matrix like:

```
  {
  { "1", "2", "3", NULL },
  { "4", "5", "6", NULL },
  NULL
  }
```

so I did

```
 int ROW = 0;
 for (int i = 0; matrix[i][0] != NULL; i+)
 {
     ROW++;
 }
```

same for columns and I have this error

```
error: comparison between pointer and integer
```

but what I dont understant is if I have

```
char *tab[] = {"1", "2", NULL};
int len = 0;
for(int i = 0; tab[i] != NULL; i++)
{
    len ++;
}
```

there it works.

Can someone explain what happens in the case of the matrix?

Thank you.

Comment: why `[i][0]`? That access the *inner element* of the *inner array*. You just want to compare the inner array. To illustrate, in your first example, `matrix[2]` is `NULL`, and that's where the row ends. Not `matrix[2][0]`. Also that `i+` is not valid syntax, though I assume that's a mistake while writing the question

Comment: ok I that's how matrices works I didn't understood that like this. thank you

Comment: `for (int i = 0; matrix[i][0] != NULL; i+)` does that even compile (specifically that increment step that..  isn't) ?. Also, show the full declaration of that matrix; not just the initializer.

Comment: I found the solution thank's to @Chase still thank you